# How to access multiple dataset using dbfit?

Tags: mysql, dbfit

My procedure is returning 3 dataset? For DB testing we are using DBFit. How Can i retrieve all dataset?

Using this to get first dataset

```
!|Store Query|CALL `USP_dbfit_tes`()|outtable|
------------
!|Query|<<outtable|
```

Sample proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_dbfit_tes`()
BEGIN
select 1;
select 2;
select 3;
END
```

Comment: [Store Query](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html#store-query) is not meant to be used like that that is the impression i get when i look into the manual.. If you want to execute a procedure you need to use [Execute Procedure](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html#execute-procedure)

Comment: Very very very wierd database unit test i found this claim in the documention `This will pass because the order is correct
|Ordered Query|SELECT n FROM ( SELECT 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 ) x|`  SQL tables/resultsets are by ANSI/ISO SQL standards definition **orderless** and does not have a fixed order unless you have a column with a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key in the `ORDER BY` then the resultset is true 100% deterministic(fixed)..

Comment: As `ORDER BY` on a non unique values only can still result into non deterministic (random) resultset.. In fact without `ORDER BY` the SQL engine is free to return the records in anny order that best suits the situation.